Signal processing of dominant components in exponential modes
I am doing theoretical computer science (TCS) research, where I encountered this problem of signal processing as a subroutine in my algorithm design.
The problem can be understood as given a threshold $\gamma\in \mathbb{R}^+$, and a signal in the form of the sum of non-increasing exponentials:
$$f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^M \alpha_i e^{\lambda_i t}=\sum_{i=1}^M \alpha_i z_i^t,$$
where $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha_i|<1$, $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re e(\lambda_i)\leq0$, and $z$ is the unit disk in the complex plane, we want to estimate each $\lambda_i$ with dominant coefficients $|\alpha_i| \geq \gamma$. Such a problem can be solved by Prony's method when a total number of $N=2M$ samples of $f(t)$ is provided. Yet, in our cases, the $M$ could be extremely large so that the total number of samples should satisfy $N\ll M$. A fair assumption in our cases is that the dominant exponential modes $z_i$ such that $|\alpha_i| \geq \gamma$ in the signal is sparse, meaning that modes that satisfy the condition have an upper-bounded number, say $K$. In such circumstances, we may expect even that though the total number $N$ of samples of $f(t)$ is prescribed to be small, an algorithm could still be designed to address the problem. Has this problem been studied in the signal-processing community before? Some references to this problem are welcome.
PS: Right now, I am trying to solve the problem by treating modes that $|\alpha_i|<\gamma$ as noises in Prony's method. As a lot of studies for the problem are numerical-oriented, some references on theoretical guarantees of Prony's method can also be helpful as I am in the TCS community.

Be aware that the fitting of exponentials can be very badly conditioned, with small changes in data able to cause large changes in the best fit parameters, so where the fitting of exponentials can be avoided, I highly recommend doing so.
Methods that I'm aware of for fitting exponentials can be classified as either variations on a theme of Prony, non-linear least squares optimisation, or integral system identification.
An excellent reference for variations on a theme of Prony and non-linear least squares optimisation is:

Hokanson, J. (2013). Numerically stable and statistically efficient algorithms for large scale exponential fitting (Doctoral dissertation, Rice University).

Regarding the integral system identification method, you can find several instances of people discussing it over on the Mathematics Stack Exchange to fit exponentials, for example here, and a peer reviewed paper that references all the other key papers is:

Lecca, P., Lecca, M., Maestri, C. A., & Scarpa, M. (2021). Biexponential fitting for noisy data with error propagation. Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences, 44(13), 10154-10171.

Integral system identification inherently assumes that your model is an accurate description of the data, so won't provide an optimal fit of the exponential exponents in the least squares sense when it isn't. Nevertheless, in my experience it provides a good initial guess and has low computational cost.
Using integral system identification as an initial guess for non-linear least squares optimisation achieves good results in my experience. If you want to force non-exponential terms to be fit along with exponential terms, then you must use integral system identification and/or non-linear least squares optimisation, however that isn't a concern for you as all your terms are exponentials. The use of non-linear least squares methods always runs the risk of finding a local rather than global minimum.
My work with the "variations on a theme of Prony" has been with respect to subspace system identification methods, and there have been a few key breakthroughs since Prony, with the final major algorithm in that space being the "Hankel Total Least Squares" method (Hokanson, 2013), which also achieves good results in my experience. Conceptually subspace system identification methods are very nice as they empirically decompose data into signal and noise, and they don't require an initial guess, but comes at a higher computational cost.
